# Schwabl states that a change in external parameters cannot increase entropy. If so, how can an adiabatic process be irreversible?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am working my way through trying to understand statistical physics, and this particular, apparent inconsistency has had me stuck for days. Any help or advice would be hugely appreciated.

I was reading the following in Schwabl's Statistical Mechanics:

[image: the page from Schwabl]

My question then, is how can an adiabatic process (one without any heat transfer) ever be irreversible? This page would imply that entropy can only increase because of heat transfer. However, according to the internet, irreversible adiabatic compression of a gas is a thing.

Comment: unless you compress very (infinitely) slowly, the particles will not be in true equilibrium in terms of the energy storage modes. that'll break it from reversibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During adiabatic process there is no *heat* transfer; the definition does not state anything about entropy. The adiabatic processes which do conserve entropy are called isentropic and they are, in fact, reversible. For the examples of irreversible adiabatic processes you can look up an isenthalpic process.

Hope this helps.